# Text toggle animate jumps

Tags: jquery, text, jquery-animate

I have a problem, what i don't know how to solve, because it's looks like a jQuery bug, but i'm not sure in it. I've tried to make a nice animation to the head of my site, but it fails, and the 2 letters(B,S) jumps down, while the animation is in progress. I don't know why does it do this.

There's the site, where's i'm testing it:
http://ihaveaproblem.brownstyle.eu/

Please help me, what should i do with it?
I hope you can help me :)

PS: These problems are only in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added this css

```
.top {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

and applied it to

```
<a class="atmenetes-betu top" href="#">B</a>

<a class="atmenetes-betu top" href="#">B</a>
```

it worked on FireFox

works in IE8 too

Comment: tested FF and Chrome but the animation still need work because it keeps animate more than one time and the menue buttons go down when animation is completed

Comment: Works fine, if i add this line to the .css file. But i've used a lil' modification: vertical-align: text-top;